# Will the IDisposable still get disposed if you copy its reference before the disposal?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, idisposable

Consider this:

```
interface IFoo : IDisposable { }

class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    var foo = GetFoo();

    var anotherFoo = foo;

    using(anotherFoo)
    {
    }

    // Will the object on the heap be marked for collection? 
    // Or will this confuse the garbage collector 
    // as we are copying references?
  }
}
```

That raises the more important question. *What does `Dispose()` actually do?*

Comment: `Dispose` is just method (used for resource management by convention), it has nothing to do with how GC decides if object need to be collected or not.

Comment: Oh, damn! I keep forgetting that! Sorry. So sorry. I keep forgetting that.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Please make that an answer and I'll mark it as the correct one.

Comment: In a way the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936216/why-does-garbage-collection-in-c-sharp-xna-not-dispose-of-render-targets-autom  is the opposite to this (they expected collection to cause disposal, you wondered if if disposal would affect collection), and as such the answers might fill in some gaps for you.

Comment: Awsome, @JonHanna. I am heading out but it seems like I am going to spend a lot of time reading that. It looks very interesting. I read the question and am going to come back and read the answer. Beautiful! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Dispose` method is added in consideration of the fact that resources other than managed memory (unmanaged resources) still need to be released explicitly; GC was specifically *not* design for it.

Moreover, the mechanism behind `IDisposable` is independent of the GC. When you follow the [Dispose Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you may optionally plug in your code into GC by making your class finalizable, but you do not have to do that as part of implementing `IDisposable`.

Disposing is related to cleaning up the hidden resources the object holds, not the "shell" of the object inside managed memory. Very often an object would throw `ObjectDisposedException` on attempts to use it after the call of `Dispose`.

Going back to your code, since the two variables actually refer to the same object, the `foo` variable would be referencing a disposed object after the `using` block. Therefore, calling methods or accessing properties of `foo` after `using` may raise an exception:

```
var foo = GetFoo();

var anotherFoo = foo;

using(anotherFoo)
{
}

foo.doSomethingUseful(); // <<== This may throw ObjectDisposedException!
```

Comment: `may throw` or `surely throws`?

Comment: @T.Todua It depends on the implementation. `ObjectDisposedException` is just a regular exception. An example: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/24f86ed2572ff48158b8e93aa3547d8380f4c754/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlDataReader.cs#L930.

Answer (score 3):

"Copying a reference" as you describe does not do *anything* to the original object.  It's just another way of looking up the same object via a different name -- like if you have a separate email address the mail of which always gets addressed to your mailbox.  Either way you get to the same object.  Thus if you dispose one then you dispose the other.

When you have the code:

```
using (anotherFoo) 
{
}
```

You are using the `using` syntax to ensure that the last thing that happens before the block finishes is that the `.Dispose` method on the object *referenced* by the variable `anotherFoo` will be disposed.  Thus it is exactly the same as if you had done `using (foo) { ... }`.

**Edit Responding to Comment**:

First, and most importantly, `IDisposable` has *nothing* to do with garbage collection.  That happens on its own.  In this example, since both `foo` and `anotherFoo` are local variables and not (apparently) being escaped from the method via closures, method calls, etc, they will be GC'ed almost as soon as the method call finishes.

`IDisposable`, on the other hand, is intended purely to allow you to free (generally) external resources such as OS handles like files, UI primitives, sockets, etc.  While it's true that you *definitely* want the object to dispose of it's resources when it's GC'ed, without `IDisposable` you can't control the inverse -- `IDisposable` allows you to clean up resources at the very moment when it is not being used anymore.  This allows you to engineer more deterministic solutions to problems that deal with external resources -- more than relying purely on what the GC would allow.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the semantics of what I am doing and what a `using` construct is for. Just confirming if the garbage collector also checks for a reference count as a criteria for marking objects for collection. I've got to read up Jeffrey Richter's book *CLR via C#* or *Applied .NET Framework Programming* again.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2, garbage collection never checks for reference counts, as there is no reference counting in .NET. It checks for objects that can't be referenced at all from any thread or static - a yes/no question, not a "how many?" question. The only connection this has with `IDisposable` is if something has been garbage collected, it can't be disposed any more. (It can be finalised, though).

Comment: Thank you, @JonHanna. Beautiful answer. Very insightful.

Answer (score 1):

Think of every variable, parameter, or other storage location of any reference type as holding a token of the form "Object #291" [but with different numbers], and figure that the system has some magical mystical ability to locate any object given a token of that form and either access its fields or tell it to do something.  Calling `Dispose` on something tells it "Your services are no longer required.  Once you return from this method, you may be abandoned at any time without further notice.  Make of that what you will."  The normal expectation is that if the object has asked any outside entity, anywhere in the universe, to do something on its behalf, the object will tell that outside entity that it no longer needs to do so.

Suppose Object #291 is a `File`.  It has asked the operating system to give it exclusive access to a file on disk, and the operating system responded to that request by returning with a file handle; nobody can access that file without that handle.  Calling `Dispose` on object #291 will instruct it to tell the operating system that it no longer needs access to that file, and that it will no longer use the handle for any purpose.  Once that has happened, Object #291 will no longer have access to the file on disk, and any attempt to read data from Object #291 will fail.

Note that--with one exception--the behavior of Object #291 will not be affected by the number of references that exist to it.  The only time that the number of references matters is when the number of "strong rooted references" drops to zero.  When that occurs, an object will cease to exist unless it has requested notification of abandonment.  If an object has requested such notification (by implementing a method called `Finalize`) then the first time it is found to be abandoned the system will ensure it is resurrected long enough to run its `Finalize` method before it ceases to exist.